# How do I catalog files on several external hard drives that I want to store off-line?

Tags: windows-xp, cataloging

I have quite a few external hard drives that I want to store off-line, and possibly off-site.

The contents is not saved in a structured manner, however; basically  there's lots of project data for lots of projects.

Is there any software for Windows XP that will catalog all the hard drives, so I can search the catalog, find the files, and get the ID of the disk that has the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the freeware [Gentibus CD](http://www.gentibus.com/). 
It works well for all file types and has a good and quick search function (that you can see in the image below):

[image]

Comment: better avoid using proprietary software and/or proprietary file formats (see my answer for an alternative).

Comment: @eadmaster: We are all of us sure that our answer is the best, which is why it is advisable not to comment on or to down-vote other answers. Especially an answer dating from 4 years ago, and which at the time was accepted as being the best.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite is by far [Cathy](http://www.mtg.sk/rva/)! It's very fast! works superbly, creates small compact catalogs.  Its only 59KB in size. I bet you can't find a tinier app for this purpose anywhere else!

See [here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-file-disk-catalog-organizer.htm#Cathy) for other alternatives.

My ideal solution is something like Cathy with these features as well:

- Auto snapshot Drives on a scheduled period, storing incremental images. (You can sort of do this using a task scheduler and git or mercurial I suppose, but haven't tried it yet)
- Have a compare option as well. (See [FilePro](http://www.saleensoftware.com/FilePro) which has this option)
- Then sync my various PCs and hard drives via dropbox/others

And voila! I have instant search access to all my Disks, plus a backup archive to see my list of files in case of disaster.

I just found [ScanFS](http://www.saleensoftware.com/ScanFS.aspx) today, but it had some errors while scanning a catalog, and not as Hard Drive centric as Cathy.

Oh that reminds me, I forgot my most often used one that has now been unsupported since 2011 http://locate32.cogit.net/
That can also be used as a cataloger though it requires more effort in adding databases. Great for searching but poor for browsing.

So my final recommendation is still cathy. Damn I have so many great ideas for Cathy, but  the author is unwilling to release the source (i asked).

---

Some more research links:

- http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=1716
- http://www.indexyourfiles.com/
- http://www.softprime.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Where is it?](http://www.whereisit-soft.com/)

> WhereIsIt is an application written for Windows operating systems, and designed to help you maintain and organize a catalog of your computer media collection, including CD-ROMs and DVDs, audio CDs, diskettes, removable drives, hard drives, network drives, remote file servers, or any other present or future storage media device Windows can access as a drive.

It's shareware.

Answer (score 2):

[there are a lot of free alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/gwhere/), **but**, if you don't need fancy stuff like image thumbnailing, metadata extraction, etc. i've found the best solution is to use **regular plaintext files** generated with:

- `dir /s /b > myindex.dir` (on Windows, store file names only)
- `du -ac > myindex.du`  (on Linux, store file names + sizes)
- `rhash --crc32 --sfv -r . > myindex.sfv` ([multiplatform tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rhash/), store file names + sizes + moddates + hashes to easily find duplicates)

advantages:

- you can read, edit and search plaintext files anywhere, on any OS (you are not bound to any proprietary file format, no need to install any specific software)
- index generation is usually faster than any disk cataloger software (because they usually build binary search trees)

downsides:

- interactive file tree browsing is not possible currently (see my requests [here](https://superuser.com/questions/684053/disk-space-analyzer-that-can-read-du-output) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/cdcat/feature-requests/31/))
- linear search is slower than binary search, but for small datasets is acceptable, especially in modern computers...

tips:

- you can sort the indexes in folders like "burned_discs", "external_hdds", "internal_hdds", "pendrives", etc.
- if you are not comfortable with the command-line you can add a [shortcut in the right-click menu of your filemanager](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) to generate the index of any folder...

Comment: We dont really need to hash unless we need to detect dupes right

Answer (score 2):

[VVV (Virtual Volumes View)](http://vvvapp.sourceforge.net/) is an alternative free and open-source application that runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can always roll-yer-own from the commandline.  I use this in Cygwin to create md5 checksums for data files getting backed up to data DVD.  My primary use is verifing the data after burning, but I keep the file (renamed to reflect the disc label, and moved to a common directory with md5 files of other backups).  Searching is as easy as grep'ing through that directory for a filename or keyword (say, a project name that might be found in folder names, since the md5 will store relative paths for each file).

In your case, assuming the data drive was mounted to E:, I'd start in /cygdrive/e/:

```
$ ( cd /cygdrive/e/ ; find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum >> ~/e-drive.md5.txt ; cp ~/e-drive.md5.txt . )
```

That's everything on the drive, so the drive can be disconnected and stored.  Now move the md5 file into wherever you're archiving the md5 files, and give it a more identifiable name:

```
$ mv ~/e-drive.md5.txt "~/My Documents/Archive Drives/New_E_Drive_Label.md5.txt"
```

When you need a file, or a project, search for a known keyword (or string of them -- say, only show .DOC files associated with Project X):

```
$ cd "~/My Documents/Archive Drives"
$ grep "Project X" * | grep -i doc
New_E_Drive_Label.md5.txt:53:0123456789abcdef0123456  Projects/Project X/Design.doc  
New_E_Drive_Label.md5.txt:54:0123456789abcdef0123456  Projects/Project X/Testing.doc  
New_E_Drive_Label.md5.txt:55:0123456789abcdef0123456  Projects/Project X/World Domination.doc
Some_Other_Drive.md5.txt:2:0123456789abcdef0123456  Project X rulez.doc
Old_Broken_Drive.md5.txt:17:0123456789abcdef0123456  What is this Project X again.doc
```

... you get the idea.  That's certainly not the prettiest output, but it cleans up nice with a little perl/python.  Or import it into a spreadsheet or database, test your awk skillz, whatever.

Comment: md5 hashing is slower than crc32, better stick with cksum or rhash (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

use **[JR Directory Printer](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jdirprint.htm)** to catalog the drives, output in TXT files, easy to search.

*JR Directory Printer is freeware and portable.*

Comment: @Molly7244 Does it give folder/file sizes ? I think the du option would work best (linux shell in Win) ? But if this does, nothing beats a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use WinCatalog (nag), [Disk Explorer Pro 3](https://portableapps.com/node/38699), and a bunch of others.

Then I tried the du option thinking text would be the simplest option. Not only did it result in a file size of 1/2 G, search would be within Notepad which is kludgy (doesnt filter non-matches)

Then I went back to the DEPro3, not only is file size for the same drive just **39KB**, its search is fast and filters other crud out, and is great for organizing many drives.

Imagine cataloging many drives with du !!

Time to index: du & VVV took > 2 hours; WinCat - forever; **DEPro3 - 5 min**!! - heck was I impressed !

Most of all, size of resulting indexed file matters if you are storing it in a cloud drive, specially during sync.

Comment: Did you checked download link to DEPro3 you posted? Looks like download domain is expired

Comment: I guess you are referring to the final link, yeah it didn't work for me either (I had downloaded it years back - must be defunct now). I will hunt it down and re-post.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the final link, yeah it didn't work for me either (I had downloaded it years back - must be defunct now). I will hunt it down and re-post. Update: Well I searched and most of the hits seemed iffy. Guess he has closed shop...sorry ! Great piece of software.